# Substring between 2 known chars

Tags: javascript

Im looking for a quick and inexpensive way to get a substring from a url looking like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZK-vdEf2rvBhvAmdrKt1xHNlCehVV-WHDShkZUUaBM/edit#gid=0
```

The part i'm after is:

```
1oZK-vdEf2rvBhvAmdrKt1xHNlCehVV-WHDShkZUUaBM
```

So we know that we want the value between the 4th '/' and the 5th '/' (zerobased index).

One solution could be something like:

```
function getPosition(str, m, i) {
   return str.split(m, i).join(m).length;
}

var url = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZK-vdEf2rvBhvAmdrKt1xHNlCehVV-WHDShkZUUaBM/edit#gid=0;

var firstOccurence = getPosition(url,'/',4);
var secondOccurence = getPosition(url,'/',5);

var result = url.substring(firstOccurence, secondOccurence);
```

Any tips om improvemnets? Could this be made without having to call `getPosition()` 2 times?

Comment: `url.split\`/\`[4]`

Comment: This one worked!  Dunno how but it works..Thanks!
Thanks for the other answers but iḿ gonna stick with this,. If you want to make an answer of it iĺl accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the split method from String:

```
var result = url.split('/');
```

It will return an array, you can access the part you want by index:

```
result[4];
```

Or even:

```
result.slice(-2)[0];
```

Using *string literals* you can short it to:

```
url.split`/`[4]
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Comment: This solution is awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```js
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZK-vdEf2rvBhvAmdrKt1xHNlCehVV-WHDShkZUUaBM/edit#gid=0';

var result = url.match(/spreadsheets\/d\/([^\/]+)\/?/);
if(result){
 console.log(result[1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oZK-vdEf2rvBhvAmdrKt1xHNlCehVV-WHDShkZUUaBM/edit#gid=0';

var part = url.replace('https://', '').split(/\//g)[3]
console.log(part)
```